# Wrong referrer when using Mixpanel with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, mixpanel

I am working on a turbolinks enabled Rails project and I just faced the following problem: I need to create a Mixpanel "funnel" which rely on the page referrer. The problem is that it doesn't get changed when you use turbolinks.

Example:
Facebook > Page 1 > Page 2 > ... Page N

- Page 1 referrer - facebook.com (correct)
- Page 2 referrer - facebook.com (not correct)
  ...
- Page N referrer - facebook.com (not correct)

Any ideas for solving this such a problem and using turbolinks at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: I just found a workaround solution. You can pass the referrer and the referring_domain as parameters to Mixpanel. I am getting them from the Rails request object and rendering them in the javascript which will do the Mixpanel tracking.

Comment: Can you give an example to your solution? ```<script type="text/javascript">
    var pagePath = {{Page Path}};
  mixpanel.track("Page View", {"Page Path": pagePath,"referrer":document.referrer});
</script>```